# seaborn pointplot above swarmplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

I try to plot group wise median values using seaborn's `pointlot` on top of a swarmplot. Even though I call pointPlot second, the point plot ends up behind the swarmplot. How can I change the 'layer order' such that the point plot is in front of the swarmplot?

```
datDf=pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,100,100)})
datDf['group']=np.random.randint(0,5,100)
sns.swarmplot(data=datDf,x='group',y='values')
sns.pointplot(data=datDf,x='group',y='values',estimator=np.median,join=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zorder` property to set proper [drawing order](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

datDf=pd.DataFrame({'values':np.random.randint(0,100,100)})
datDf['group']=np.random.randint(0,5,100)
sns.swarmplot(data=datDf,x='group',y='values',zorder=1)
sns.pointplot(data=datDf,x='group',y='values',estimator=np.median,join=False, zorder=100)
plt.show()
```

[image]